# Attaching to different parts of shared memory not working properly

Tags: c, shared-memory, mmap

I am using shared memory for communication between two different process. I am creating shared memory of 16 MB size. I am trying to attach two different parts of the shared memory. One for writing and other for reading. Even though it maps to different memory address but when one is modified other also gets changed. I must be doing something wrong. Below is the code snippet where I am attaching to multiple shared memory location.

```
void createCommPool ()
    {
      CommSet set1;
      int shmid1;
      int fd1;
      int r;
      void * ptr;
      void * ptr_res;
      umask (0);          
      fd1 = open(SHARED_MEMORY0, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR, 0777);
      if (fd1 == -1)
      error_and_die("open");
      r = ftruncate(fd1, region_size);
      if (r != 0)
      error_and_die("ftruncate");
      ptr = mmap(0, sizeof(struct operation_st), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,  
            ,MAP_SHARED,fd1,sizeof(struct operation_st));
      if (ptr == MAP_FAILED)
      error_and_die("mmap");
      close(fd1);
      set1.shm_addr = ptr;

      fd1 = open(SHARED_MEMORY0, O_RDWR, 0777);
      if (fd1 == -1)
      error_and_die("open");
      fprintf(stderr,"The value of the file descriptor:%d\n",fd1);
      if (lseek(fd1,sizeof(struct operation_st),SEEK_SET)<0)
      {
       fprintf(stderr,"could not perform lseek\n");
       perror("lseek");
      }

     ptr_res = mmap(0,sizeof(struct operation_st), PROT_READ| PROT_WRITE,              
                    MAP_SHARED,fd1,0);
     if (ptr_res == MAP_FAILED)
      error_and_die("mmap2");
      close(fd1);
     set1.shm_addr_res = ptr_res;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

For data in shared memory, avoid the influence of bytes alignment with `pack`:

```
#pragma pack(1)
your shared memory code
#pragma unpack
```

Comment: I have aligned the structure properly so that there is no influence of bytes. What is wrong with my code that it attaches to the same part of the shared memory not to different parts.

Comment: @Kunal it seems that lseek won't influence the mmap call with fd as an argument. To be verified.

Comment: I tried to specify sizeof(struct operation_st) as the mmap offset parameter but it was giving MAP_FAILED error.

Comment: I found out my mistake. I was passing the offset not in multiple of the page size so it was not able to MAP_FAILED error.

Comment: @Kunal that stands on.

Answer (score 0):

lseek does not have any effect on the mapping of the shared memory. The offset parameter should be used in order to map to the different part of the shared memory. The offset should be in multiples of page size.